# backbone JS select won't work

Tags: backbone.js, pug

i have a backbone JS application, it has a select on the UI, like this:

(template is written in Jade)

```
select.color
  option(value='-1') --select color--
  option(value='0') red
  option(value='1') blue
```

the application is like this:

```
events: 
  'change .color': 'changeColor'

changeColor: () ->
  idx = $(@el).find('.color').val()
  color = $(@el).find('.color').filter(idx).text()
  alert("Color is : #{idx}:#{color}")
```

however when i ran it, it only printout the correct idx but no text. i tried to use `$(@el).find('.color').filter(':selected').text()` 
directly, it wont' work either. anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use .find() instead of .filter() as filter will filter the select not the child options. So:

```
$(@el).find('.color').find(':selected').text()
```

Ps Backbone automatically adds find to the view for you so:

```
$(@el).find('.color');
```

is equivalent to:

```
@.$('.color')
```